# ModelForm disable imageField if empty

Tags: python, django, image, modelform

I have a form that allows users to upload an image.  If they don't upload an image a default image is displayed.  I want it that if they don't upload an image, the image field is disabled.  I thought the if statement at the end of the form would work - but it didn't.  Here's the form forms.py:

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name', 'description', 'url', 'product_type', 'price', 'image', 'image_url']
        labels = {
            'name': 'Product Name',
            'url': 'Product URL',
            'product_type': 'Product Type',
            'description': 'Product Description',
            'image': 'Product Image',
            'image_url': 'Product Image URL',
            'price': 'Product Price'
        }
        widgets = {
            'description': Textarea(attrs={'rows': 5}),
        }

    if Product.image is None:
        form.fields['image'].disabled = True
```

and here's the models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    product_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product_images', default='product_images/default.png', null=True)
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('index', kwargs={})
```

I tried removing the default='product_images/default.png' - that didn't seem to work.  I tried null=True and that seemed to crash the page.  What am I missing?

Here's the relevant part template:

```
{% if product.image.url %}
    {% if product.image_url %}
        <img class="img-fluid" src="{{ product.image_url }}" />
    {% endif %}
    <img class="img-fluid" src="{{ product.image.url }}" />
{% endif %}
```

This shows both types of images - uploaded to local, and link to external.  The problem I'm trying to solve is that default image appears below the external image - I want to hide the default image.  I'm early in learning Django and Python so I apologize if I'm mixing things up.

Comment: If you disable image field in the Product form then how users will upload the image?

Comment: if Product.image is None: form.fields['image'].disabled = True in the form is supposed to disable the image field in no image is selected.  I only want that field disabled if the user isn't uploading an image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that what you want is not disabling an ImageField in form. Just try setting `blank=True` for image field in your model and remove `default` parameter.

```
# models.py
class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product_images', blank=True, null=True)
    # image_url = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)  # Remove this field, you don't need it.
    ...
```

Also, remove `image_url` from model and from form.

Then in template put something like:

```
{% if product.image %}
    <img class="img-fluid" src="{{ product.image.url }}" />
{% else %}
    <img class="img-fluid" src="/media/product_images/default.png" />
{% endif %}
```

Comment: That throws an error "ValueError at /products/post_url/ - The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it." - not sure how to fix that.

Also, I need the image_url for when an image is being pulled from the web, as opposed to being uploaded and used locally.

Comment: Scratch that - I changed the "if" statement and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

You can alter fields in the `Form`'s `__init__()` method:

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name', 'description', 'url', 'product_type', 'price', 'image', 'image_url']
        labels = {
            'name': 'Product Name',
            'url': 'Product URL',
            'product_type': 'Product Type',
            'description': 'Product Description',
            'image': 'Product Image',
            'image_url': 'Product Image URL',
            'price': 'Product Price'
        }
        widgets = {
            'description': Textarea(attrs={'rows': 5}),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance:
            # If the instance has no image, they haven't uploaded anything
            if self.instance.image is None:
                # Alter the field in the form
                self.fields['image'].disabled = True
```

You have to be careful about what you're referencing. For example, `Product.image` is going to give you the attribute on the `Product` class, which isn't `None`, because you assigned it `models.ImageField()`. You want to reference an *instance* of `Product`, which is what you can get from `ModelForm().instance`.

Comment: Thanks Jen - especially for explaining why (which makes sense) - that really helps as I learn.  However, this didn't work - the default image is still showing.  Perhaps disabling the field isn't the way to make it work?  Not sure what else can be done.

Comment: Displaying an image and disabling a field are two different things...can you share the template you're using to display the form?

Comment: I've added the {% if %} statement I'm using to the post.  Let me know if you need to see more.  Also, I apologize in advance if I'm mixing things up - still very new to Django and Python.